# Gerrit Prolog Rules: Getting started

Tags: prolog, gerrit

I would like to alter the commit rules for gerrit but somehow I am seemingly unable to follow the steps described in the cookbook (for example here:
http://saros-build.imp.fu-berlin.de/gerrit/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_the_rules_pl_file )

On my local gerrit system I simply created an empty project

```
ssh user@localhost -p 29418 gerrit create-project --empty-commit --name demo-project
```

Next I cloned the new project

```
git clone ssh://user@localhost:29418/demo-project
```

Then according to the description I tried

```
/demo-projectmaster% git fetch origin refs/meta/config:config
```

which resulted in

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/meta/config
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Feels like something very basic...
Thanks,
JS

Answer (score 0):

it was due to missing access criteria.
I had to (in gerrit) grant the user explicit Read/Submit rights on refs/meta/config despite the user being in the administrator group.

Jörg